# how to make a linear layout automatically scrollable while dynamically adding its content

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, horizontal-scrolling

My application containing different layouts.one of them is a linear layout.it's content is dynamically adding.i want to make this layout horizontally scrollable while adding its content.for that i wrote the code given below..

```
 <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/scoreballparent_layout"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:orientation="horizontal"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_above="@+id/score_layout">
  <HorizontalScrollView android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
  android:id="@+id/scrollView1" 
  android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
  >
      <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
      android:id="@+id/scoreball_layout" 
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      >

      </LinearLayout>
   </HorizontalScrollView>
 </LinearLayout>
```

it is working..but i want to scroll it automatically while adding contents...can anybody help me plz...

more source code:

```
    private void scoreball_display(String score)
    {
        addscoreball = new Button(getApplicationContext());
        addscoreball.setId(134);
        if(score=="WD" || score=="NB")
        {
            addscoreball.setTextAppearance(this,R.style.plainText);
        }
        else{
            addscoreball.setTextAppearance(this,R.style.BoldText);
        }

        addscoreball.setText(score);
        addscoreball.setSingleLine(true);
        addscoreball.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable      (R.drawable.white_ball));
        addscoreball.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
        addscoreball.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams addscoreball_Params = 
            new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(35,35);  
        scoreballlayout.addView(addscoreball,addscoreball_Params);

        }
```

in this method it is adding more contents to my layout...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to update your UI when new element is added

first initialize HorizonatlScrollView using the following code

```
HorizontalScrollView s = (HorizontalScrollView) findViewById(R.id.HorizontalScrollView01);
```

when a new element is added use the following line there to scroll your HorizontalScrollView

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                s.fullScroll(HorizontalScrollView.FOCUS_RIGHT);

            }
        });
```

Thanks
Deepak

Comment: in scoreball_display method after you add view you have not called runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
.....

Answer (score 3):

Put `<ScrollView>` as parent layout...

Comment: u mean parent layout of horizontal scrollview?

Answer (score 0):

There is a *scrollTo* method, see http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/HorizontalScrollView.html#scrollTo(int, int)